# Automatically detect an image collage

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, hough-transform

I'm trying to automatically detect if an image is a collage vs a single photograph. I'm not too concerned with edge cases. What I'm trying to solve is rectangular collages like below. I've tried edge detection (canny) + vertical and horizontal sobel filtering + line detection (Hough transform) to try to identify perpendicular lines but am getting too many false positives. I'm not very good at image processing so any input would be welcome. Thx!

[image] [image]

Comment: Did you find and/or implement a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a challenge, because images "have the right" to contain verticals and horizontals, and there can be sudden changes in the background due to occlusion for instance.

But a clue can help you: the borders between two pictures are perfectly straight, "unnaturally" straight, and they are long.

Comment: That is a good idea. I'm thinking of maybe creating custom elongated filters to try to detect "long" and "very straight" lines but even then I feel like I'd still have too many false positives for this to be useful.

Comment: @mkohram: no, detect edges as usual and check straightness.